# How to create a custom onChange with formik

Tags: formik

I need to create a custom onChange event handler. I'm using formik library. I want to add a dash when a user inputs the 6. character in a field and remove the dash when the users removes the character in front o the dash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.

```js
  const [field, meta] = useField(props);

  const onChange = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    let newEvent = event;
    let value: string = event.target.value;

    console.log(event);

    if (value.length === 7 && value.at(-1)?.match(/[0-9]/)) {
      newEvent.target.value = `${value.slice(0, 6)}-${value.at(-1)}`;
    }

    if (value.length === 7 && value.at(-1) === "-") {
      newEvent.target.value = `${value.slice(0, 6)}`;
    }
    return field.onChange(newEvent);
  };
```